# virtualenv binary not found after pip3 install

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm working on macos and using python 3.8. I executed `pip3 install virtualenv` which seemed to run without errors. Now however, `virtualenv` on the command line comes back with a *command not found* error. No output from a *which* command either. Where would pip3 have placed the virtualenv binary?

Thanks!

Comment: `pip3 show --files virtualenv`

Comment: Absolutely did the trick.